# Is (begin ...) a functional construct?

Tags: scheme, racket

Is

```
...
(begin (command1 arg1) 
       (command2 arg2)
       (command3 arg3))
...
```

a functional construct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"`begin` is used to sequence assignments, input/output, or other operations that cause side effects." R. Kent Dybvig, "The Scheme Programming Language", Third Edition, Section 5.2. (Retrieved from: http://www.scheme.com/tspl3)

So begin is not a purely functional construct.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a lot pf pure functional code in Scheme by avoiding side effects. The need for `begin` in any form is nonexistent when you do not have side effects since every expression in a `begin` that is not the very last and that does not have side effects is dead code.

You have explicit `begin` in `lambda` expressions and every derived syntax (like `let`).